# Group a dataframe based on sequence breaks in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame, which has a column of integer values. I need to form a grouping variable that identifies sequence breaks in that column. For instance, I could create another column of ascending integers that adds one whenever the original column's value is not greater than its lagged value. How do I do this?

E.g. if I have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,4,6,78,3,56,78,23))
```

I need some way to produce new table with column B:

```
df$B <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
```

I have tried e.g. with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate(B = 1,
              B = case_when(A < lag(A), B + 1))
```

That is not quite correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group variable based on continuous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644455/group-variable-based-on-continuous-values)

Comment: .. not an exact duplicate, but maybe helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` and `diff` which will increment the value every time the sequence is broken

```
cumsum(c(-1, diff(df$A)) < 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

---

We can also integrate into `dplyr` chain to get

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(B = cumsum(c(-1, diff(A)) < 0))

#   A B
#1  1 1
#2  2 1
#3  4 1
#4  6 1
#5 78 1
#6  3 2
#7 56 2
#8 78 2
#9 23 3
```

---

A hacky way using `lag` could be

```
df %>%
  mutate(B = cumsum(c(-1, (A - lag(A))[-1]) < 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. Yes, I see now that `diff`is more straightforward option than `lag`.

Comment: @Antti, If you just need to identify the breaks of the sequence why not : `df$B <- c(diff(df$A),NA)>0` , of course if you requiere it as in your column B, this answer is great.

Comment: @ChrissPaul the value is in increasing order so breaks happen only when the value decreases from previous value. I am not clear on how you will get breaks using `c(diff(df$A),NA)>0` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I am wrong, sorry. However, I understood the "indicator of sequence breaks" in the question as just and indicator of where (index) there is break of the sequence, in that case my answer should be: `df$B <- c(NA, diff(df$A))<0`: in case the difference is negative, then there is a break.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, B := cumsum(A - shift(A, fill = first(A)) < 0) + 1][]
#    A B
#1:  1 1
#2:  2 1
#3:  4 1
#4:  6 1
#5: 78 1
#6:  3 2
#7: 56 2
#8: 78 2
#9: 23 3
```